# Difference between %llx and %p while printing a pointer inside driver code

Tags: c, linux-kernel, driver, linux-device-driver

It seems that casting a `void*` pointer (allocated by kmalloc) to `unsigned long long` changes it. Printing them with `%p` and `%llx` gives different values. Why is it so?  Can anyone explain?

Following is a simple repro for that:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/init.h>

void* kbuff;
int init_module(void)
{

    kbuff = kzalloc(sizeof(char), GFP_KERNEL);
    pr_info("%p %llx\n",kbuff, (unsigned long long)kbuff);
    return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
    kfree(kbuff);
}
```

The `dmesg` output comes out to be as follows

```
[67355.673465] 000000003aeb0247 ffff9ef657a58c00
```

Comment: Because when you pass a pointer to `%llx` you are passing the wrong datatype which invokes UB. This is because the format of pointers can differ much between platforms, you cannot assume, that it can be well represented by a `long long int`. Did you even bother to cast it? If not, casting it explicitly to `(unsigned long long)` might improve your results.

Comment: I tried that as well. But still they are different.

Comment: It might help to show the exact code and the output(s) you observe.

Comment: @Ctx Thanks for the quick response. I have edited the question with relevant code.

Comment: Pointers are hashed by security reasons. Try _%px_ instead. I'll write an answer later on. Ah, somebody beat me to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation of `printk()` (which pr_info calls):

> ## Pointer Types
>
> Pointers printed without a specifier extension (i.e unadorned %p) are
>   hashed to give a unique identifier without leaking kernel addresses to user
>   space. On 64 bit machines the first 32 bits are zeroed. If you *really*
>   want the address see %px below.

So, this is a security measure. Use the `%px` format specifier to print the real address (which should match now)

Comment: The documentation is available at [www.kernel.org/../printk-formats.html](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/core-api/printk-formats.html)