# why the out of %p and %x is different in linux driver

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have write a linux driver program.
and the main code is:

```
struct file_operations dummy_fops = {
    open:       dummy_open,
    release:    dummy_release,
    read:       dummy_read,
    write:      dummy_write,
};

ssize_t dummy_read (struct file *filp, char __user * buf, size_t count,
                                loff_t * offset)
{
    int c = 0;
    pr_info("Nothing to read guy\n");
    pr_info("address %p %x", &c, &c); // this is output
    return 0;
}
```

I tapped the command:

```
make
sudo insmod my_module
sudo cat /dev/my_module
dmesg
```

the main output is:

```
[10004.473406] Someone tried to open me
[10004.473425] Nothing to read guy
[10004.473431] address 32ba0e06 eef1ff1c
[10004.473446] Someone closed me
```

Why the output %p 32ba0e06 and the output %x eef1ff1c is different?

Comment: Because `%x` is wrong for printing pointers... and for `%p` you should do `(void*)&c` to get it real correct

Comment: Basically, you are cheating on your compiler. Or more precise on `pr_info` function. You promise to provide an argument of type `void*` and another one of type `int` but instead you provide 2 arguments of type `int*`. They don't necessarily have same size and representation than what you promised. Or they could be passed in different ways to the function. If the function then interprets the memory content as you told it, it accesses wrong parts of your parameters and the result is wrong.

Comment: @SupportUkraine If i use (void*)&c, the output of it is also less than 0xC0000000, the 0xC0000000 is the start of kernel space.

Comment: @Gerhardh better as "... an argument of type `void*` and another one of type `unsigned`".

Comment: sunhang, Why does code use mis-matched specifiers and arguments? Do you have all compiler warnings enabled?  What output is seen when code runs with matching specifiers and arguments? `pr_info("address %p %x\n", (void *) &c, (unsigned) &c);`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I want to print the variable's address to testify the driver is running in kernel space which is above 0xC0000000. I just used (void*)&c to %p, usigned to %x，but the result is also the same as before, the %p 's output is less than 0xC0000000, seemingly the %x's output is correct, which is larger than 0xC0000000. I dont know why.

Comment: Are you possibly compiling a 32-bit application on a 64-bit system? Because your output is too short for a 64-bit pointer.

Comment: @Aconcagua my ubuntu is 32-bit running in virtualbox. so my system is 32-bit and the compiled app is also 32-bit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between %llx and %p while printing a pointer inside driver code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60411605/difference-between-llx-and-p-while-printing-a-pointer-inside-driver-code)

Comment: @0andriy Yes. Thank you! It helped me to learning the specifiers and arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the pointers in the Linux kernel are hashed by default for the security reasons. So, taking into account the 32-bit architecture (or the kernel compiled for 32-bit mode) there is no difference between `%px` and `%x`. The `%px` is the special pointer specifier extension that tells “I do want to print the real address”.

PS for 64-bit architecture the `%x` will print only least 32 bits, so you need to use `%lx` instead.